# Constraint for total specialization of overlapping classes SQL

Tags: sql, constraints, overlap

If I have a table `FOOD` (for instance `TOMATO`) that has overlapping total specialization classes `FOOD GROUP` (for instance `VEGETABLE` and `FRUIT`), how can I force the element `TOMATO` to be contained included in at least one of the specialization classes? My current implementation looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Food (
    Name        VARCHAR(16)     PRIMARY KEY;
)

CREATE TABLE Food_IN_FoodGroup (
    FoodName    VARCHAR(16),
    FooGrpName  VARCHAR(16),
    PRIMARY KEY (FoodName, FooGrpName),
    FOREIGN KEY (FoodName)   REFERENCES Food(Name),
    FOREIGN KEY (FooGrpName) REFERENCES FoodGroup(Name),
)

CREATE TABLE FoodGroup(
    Name        VARCHAR(16)     PRIMARY KEY;
)
```

but with this approach I could do `INSERT INTO Food VALUES ("Tomato")` without also adding it to `Food_IN_FoodGroup`. How can I create a constraint to force the tomato element to exist in a subclass?

Comment: Do you really want to do this?  Think about how you would add new rows into `Food`?  The inserts would fail because they are not in any group.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's an example implementation, I'm not entirely sure if it's the correct way to implement such a relation. But I was hoping that it might be possible to add into multiple rows simultaneously? Should the implementation be different or are there other mechanisms to prevent `Tomat` from not existing in a `FoodGroup`?

Comment: . . Of course it is possible.  I just don't think you have thought through the ramifications of your requirement.

Comment: This is such a great question, and I wish it got more activity than the above accusation.

Comment: @Corey I think the question could've been better phrased or have a better use case. I think this answers the question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167923/enforce-an-at-least-one-relationship